# Is posting in Meta the best way to get the main chat room reopened?

Tags: discussion, support, chat

It seems [the retrocomputing chat room here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38597/the-bbs) is so little used that it gets closed down all the time automatically by the system.

If somebody with appropriate powers can reopen "The BBS" that would be nice. Surely there's a few people up for a chat now and then, especially in these slow virusy times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mean, it certainly works. But the best way is to post some messages every so often so it never gets frozen in the first place.

Alternative methods of notifying a moderator include, but are not limited to:

- Flagging one of your own posts (use sparingly).
- Posting a comment on a moderator's post.
- Finding a chat room a moderator is in and pinging them.

If we had room owners, this wouldn't be as much of an issue. The BBS is pretty inactive, though, so none of the (formal and informal) ways that I know of bootstrapping the first ROs would work.